# How do I transfer data from one table view cell to another?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a favorites page. How can I let a user click on an image in one table view and then the data from the table view they clicked on is transferred to another tableview in another page?

```
@IBAction func favoritesSelected(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if toggleState == 1
    {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Star Filled-32.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        isFav = true

        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var newFave = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Favorites", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newFave.setValue("" + nameLabel.text!, forKey: "favorite")

        do
        {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch _
        {
            print("error")
        }

        //print("\(newFave)")
        print("Object saved")

        toggleState = 2
    }
```

From the code above, you can see what happens when a user clicks on the favorites button. The image changes and it uploads the name to the core data.

I'm trying to get it to go to another table view cell class so that when it gets to the favorites page, the names that were favorited will already be there.

I will show what I have in that class but I'm sure it's wrong.

```
if (result == 2)
    {
        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Favorites")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do 
        {
            var results:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

            if (results.count <= 0)
            {
                print("Either all object deleted or error")
            }
        }
        catch _
        {
            print("error")
        }


    }
    else
    {
        print("no show")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: NSNotification triggers tableView reload:**

Register the UITableView `tableView` with the notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSave:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)

func contextDidSave(sender: NSNotification) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

After the user clicks on the star in the first example and the context was saved properly, the `contextDidSave` callback will be executed and the `tableView` will load with the latest state in the DB

**Option 2: Setup UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController**

With this option, once the user clicks on the star and the context saves, iOS will trigger the update to selected cells automatically.  See this article for reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/

Answer (score 0):

In my applications with a favourite function I have done the following:

1) On my model objects have a BOOL property called favourite, with a default value of false.

2) In the table view which lists all objects, when a user taps the favourite button, set the favourite property on the corresponding model object to true and save your managed object context.

3) In the table view in which you wish to display the favourited objects, query core data for all of your model objects with a favourite property that is true and display those results. As mentioned in Christopher Harris' answer, this is trivial if you are a using an NSFetchedResultController.